WebApplicationException Equivalent In Spring Rest
I am rewriting some JAX-RS code as spring.  However, I am not sure what to do with these exceptions.
if(file == null) {
    throw new WebApplicationException(404);
}

Does spring have a similar concept?  I know about ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Not Found"); However, it is extra work to convert everything.  Currently, the endpoints just return strings, not response objects.
Thanks,

You could use the ResponseStatusException for this.

@M.Deinum That works perfect. You can give that as an answer if you want.

Judging from what you want to achieve, I assume returning a specific error code without modifying the signature of all the methods.
For Spring Web you could use the ResponseStatusException to achieve the same.
if(file == null) {
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}

Something along those lines.
